# Stop `stack install` from building internal libraries that no exes depend on?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to use `stack install` to build and install some executables. My package also has an internal library that the test suite and benchmarks depend on, but none of the executables do. But when I do `stack install`, it attempts to build the internal library. I haven't been able to find a way to stop that, trying various combinations of targets and `--skip`. Is it possible?

My root package.yaml is laid out like

```
name: my-lib

library:
  ...

internal-libraries:
  test-lib:
    ...
    dependencies:
      - my-lib

tests:
  test:
    ...
    dependencies:
      - test-lib
      ...

benchmarks:
  bench:
    ...
    dependencies:
      - test-lib
      ...
```

And the package.yamls for the executables are just

```
name: some-exe

executables:
  some-exe:
    ...
    dependencies:
      - my-lib
      ...
```

Nothing lists `test-lib` in its dependencies. `test-lib` only exists so that the benchmark can use some utilities defined in the test suite; until recently it was just part of the test suite, not a separate library, and `stack install` wasn't trying to build it.

Answer (score 0):

An option I've found is to create a separate package for just the internal library. I've created a directory `test-pkg` and moved the everything from the `internal-libraries` line down into the package.yaml in there. I also created symlinks to the source directories for my test suite and benchmarks, and assorted other relevant things found in the root of my original package.

Then I can do

```
stack install `stack ide targets 2>&1 | grep :exe:`
```

To install all the binaries.

I don't like this very much, but it seems to work.